# NSLayoutConstraint margen de UIView

Tags: swift, swift2

¿Cúal es la forma correcta de hacer un `constraint` con la constante 0 y que deje un espacio al margen de la vista?

```
 self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gestureView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
 self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: gestureView, attribute: .LeadingMargin, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```

El margen, ¿Se le debe aplicar a la primer vista o a la segunda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dejar un margen entre una vista `parentView` y un sub-vista `childView`, el orden es `childView` > `parentView`(Margin):

```
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .LeftMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .RightMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .TopMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .BottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Resulta en:

[image: Margen]

---

Es mejor usar `attribute` con el `Margin` sufijo, y dejar el `constant` a `0`. Miramos un ejemplo de porque es mejor el `Margin`:

```
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
```

Resulta en:

[image: Margen errado]

Answer (score 2):

A continuación te detallo una forma de hacerlo con el resultado. El ejemplo básicamente es un cuadrado dentro de otro.

```
// Vista contenedor
let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0), size: CGSize(width: 200.0, height: 200.0)))
container.backgroundColor = .redColor()
view.addSubview(container)

// Cuadrado interior
let square = UIView()
square.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
square.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
container.addSubview(square)

// Constraints
let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: square, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0)
let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: square, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10.0)
let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: square, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10.0)
let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: square, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: container, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10.0)
container.addConstraints([left, top, right, bottom])
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aún así, te recomiendo utilizar el `Visual Format` ya que es mucho más corto y fácil de leer. Conseguirás el mismo resultado con las siguiente constraints:

```
// Visual format constraints
let horizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[square]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["square": square])
container.addConstraints(horizontal)
let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[square]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["square": square])
container.addConstraints(vertical)
```

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, pero la pregunta iba mas sobre: "El margen, ¿Se le debe aplicar a la primer vista o a la segunda?" y como usar el atributo `.LeftMargin` o, por ejemplo, `RightMargin`

Comment: Las constraints siempre las debes aplicar teniendo en cuenta que el primer componente es la `subView` y el segundo la `superView`. En los ejemplos, la `subView` sería `square` y la `superView` el `container`. No quiere decir que no lo puedas hacer al revés, pero te será más complicado. Sobre el `.LeftMargin` no te confundas, no sirve para añadir un margen. Simplemente es la forma de indicar que la constraint hace referencia al "margen izquierdo". No es lo mismo decir "la distancia al margen izquierdo es" que decir "deja una distancia de x por mi lado izquierdo"

Comment: Por eso, si mi vista tiene un margen de 8 puntos, y le aplico un `.LeftMargin`, el constraint lo tendría en cuenta. Ahora si le aplico un `Left` no los tendría en cuenta. Es así, no?

Comment: En ese caso tendrá el mismo efecto, pero en otros no. Es complicado de explicar...